# Как сделать статистику просмотров плеера?

Tags: nginx, статистика

Всем привет, интересует вопрос по поводу реализации статистики просмотров плеера, а именно подсчет выходов на рекламу.
Имеется киносайт у него своя база фильмов и свой плеер VideoJS, заметили что с нашего сайта берут другие видео к себе на сайты. Встал вопрос узнать статистику просмотров с данного плеера и выходы на рекламу (VAST) чтобы не просто считала статистика кнопку плея, а именно засчитывало просмотр только тогда, когда сработает реклама. 
Подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону копать